Not able to exit from memtest86
Im not able to exit from memtest86+ test while booting into ubuntu. After pressing ESC, the system reboots and then enters into memtest86 screen. Tried with BIOS default option also but didnt work. I can get into grub menu, but cannot do any changes in /etc/default/grub as vi doesnt work.
I want to fix this without reinstalling the OS. Please suggest the steps.

Do you know what partition your system is on?  If not you can boot a live system to explore; even chroot across to it & work out why grub isn't offering you the option & have it rescan (update-grub etc) & correct your issue, otherwise if you already know, you can use the E key to edit an entry (here I'm talking about your existing grub with the memtest option) & enter the grub commands to boot your system from there. There is no Ubuntu 22.0; as releases are year.month in format; so its either a typo/error or you're not using Ubuntu at all.
